# Почему у вас такой неудобный редактор WYSIWYG?

Tags: обсуждение

Непонятно, зачем нужно было так всё усложнять. Чудачество, с которым просто неприятно и неудобно иметь дело. Причина, по которой приходится идти на другие площадки обсуждения. И... немного разочарования и испорченного настроения. Спасибо.

Comment: Поддерживаю предыдущего оратора. Интерфейс сайта да и концепция для детей. Сплошные рейтинги, медали, виртуальные звания. Вобщем многопользовательская игра а не площадка для обсуждения вопросов программирования. Только продажи прокаченных персонажей еще нехватает. Кстати, кто-нибудь может подсказать другие площадки для обсуждения? Раньше я ходил на RSDN.RU, но сейчас он что-то захирел два вопроса в неделю и тишина.

Comment: Во-первых, это не сайт для _обсуждения_. Тут не приветствуются длинные дискуссии. Это сайт типа "Вопрос - ответ". Задаёшь вопрос - получаешь ответ. Хотите о чём-то поговорить - идите на другие форумы, специально предназначенные для этого.

Comment: Во-вторых, критикуя - предлагай. Если что-то кажется неудобным, напишите, как нужно сделать удобно. Если что-то неприятно, напишите, что именно и как это исправить.

Comment: "Почему у вас такой неудобный редактор WYSIWYG?" - потому что это совсем не WYSIWYG, а markdown. Вот раньше с BB-кодами как-то жили и ничего, никто не жаловался, а тут WYSIWYG подавай.

Comment: Хотелось бы больше конкретики - что не устраивает, почему, что предлагаете вместо/вместе. А то выходит пришли, какашку кинули и всё, нехорошо это.

Comment: Да элементарно чудно и неудобно. Что, до вашего не было других WYSiWYG с тегами вставки кода? Полно. Всё логично и понятно. А тут - какие-то "танцы с бубнами": ни кода HTML не рассмотреть, ни тегов типа <code></code> ручками не вставить...
Ломать все привычки ради одного сайта - это того не стоит.

Comment: @IliaErastiKhubutia про код отвечу дополнением к вопросу.

Comment: не нравиться, иди на другой форум где есть перделки и свистелки

Comment: @Duoxx, [be nice](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice)

Comment: @IliaErastiKhubutia "ломать привычки" — если вы как программист не знаете markdown формат как он используется на Stack Overflow, Github, то вам стоит новые привычки приобрести — пригодится. Тэги html такие как code вы можете использовать. Постарайтесь в дополнение, а лучше вместо эмоций, конкретные вещи указать, которые вам не нравятся (и если есть идеи, то как исправить). Сайт доступен для всех: он не "у вас", а "у нас". Мета для того и существует, чтобы в том числе предложения по сайту обсуждать. Содержательные отзывы (которые личные впечатления, опираясь на факты, излагают) являются ценными

Comment: @insolor ну извините ) не сдержался

Answer (score 11):

#### Потому что это не WYSIWYG, а исходный код

Вопросы и ответы здесь пишутся на специальном языке разметки, он называется Markdown. Хранится и редактируется именно исходный код. Потом исходный код компилируется в HTML и результат показывается посетителям сайта.

Подумайте, это же по-настоящему программистский подход:

- **Это код!** Его можно писать на сайте, а можно в любимом редакторе с подсветкой синтаксиса. Можно хоть программно его генерировать. Поиск и замена в редакторе,`grep`, `sed` — всё это работает.
- **Код версионируется.** Сохраняются все правки вопросов и ответов, их авторы, время изменения — как в вашей любимой системе контроля версий. Можно посмотреть diff двух версий ответа, либо кода в вопросе и кода в ответе. Откатить к прошлой версии можно.
- Набор стилей строго ограничен. Для почти любой задачи есть единственный правильный способ решения. Блоки кода, заголовки, списки — всё отображается всегда одним и тем же образом.  Благодаря этому весь сайт выглядит чисто и гладко. Его легко и приятно читать.

  Сравните с тем, что обычно предлагают форумные редакторы: анимированные смайлики, текст всех цветов и размеров. Такой текст выглядит как порнобаннер.
  Читая его, гораздо сложнее концентрировать внимание, усталость наступает быстрее.
- Всё это **доступно через [API](https://api.stackexchange.com/) и [открытую базу данных SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/)**. Вы можете написать, например, свой чатбот, который будет присылать вам вопросы по интересной теме. А теперь представьте, что содержимое вопросов хранилось бы в каком-нибудь проприетарном, основанном на XML, формате. Его было бы тяжело обрабатывать программно.

  К счастью, используется **простой и самый популярный язык** разметки. Для работы с ним есть библиотеки, наверное, во всех популярных языках. А ещё есть универсальные инструменты вроде [pandoc](http://pandoc.org/). Хотите сохранять интересные вам ответы в `.pdf`, `.epub` или `.docx` – пожалуйста, за каких-нибудь полчаса вы напишете код, который будет это делать.
- Markdown – это **[lingua franca](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9B%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%B2%D0%B0_%D1%84%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B0) в технической документации**, особенно в проектах с открытым исходным кодом. Если вы захотите опубликовать свой проект, например, на GitHub – вам придётся написать к нему хотя бы внятное README. Поверьте, даже гениальный проект никому не нужен без минимальной документации. Так вот, писать это README вам придется на Markdown, либо на аналогичных ему языках разметки (GH поддерживает reStructuredText, AsciiDoc и другие). А WYSYWIG-редактора там нет.

---

Конкретно:

> А тут - какие-то "танцы с бубнами": ни кода HTML не рассмотреть, ни тегов типа <code></code> ручками не вставить

Код оформляется просто. Внутри строки — символ '`':

```
текст `code` текст
```

текст `code` текст

Блок кода — отступ в 4 пробела.

```
    код
    код
```

Comment: Ну, тогда мимо. Специально переучиваться на Markdown ради одного - двух комментариев - это трата времени и сил. Кому делать нечего - пусть играет в эти игрушки. Но развитию разработки кода это не способствует, как бег с тазиком цемента на ногах не помогает развитию спорта.

Comment: @IliaErastiKhubutia Понимаю, что вы привыкли к другим форматам и визуальным редакторам. Странно, что вы не встретили Markdown раньше. Попробуйте, он предельно простой. И в редакторе есть сверху кнопки для всех стилей.

Comment: @IliaErastiKhubutia насчет «развитию разработки кода это не способствует» — в моей компании способствует. Мы переносим огромный массив (тысячи статей на 10 языках) из визуального редактора в аналогичный формат разметки. Всем, кто задействован в разработке документации, новый формат работы значительно удобнее и легче.

Comment: @IliaErastiKhubutia потратить пару минут на пробежку по основам markdown - трата времени и сил? Я текст этого комментария дольше обдумывал, что ж вы лентяй такой)

Comment: @IliaErastiKhubutia markdown - это, практически, стандарт индустрии - его поддерживают Slack / Github / Stackoverflow. Выбор вместо него любого другого языка разметки увеличило бы число тех, кто с этим "любым другим языком разметки" был бы незнаком. Вам не повезло - да, но зато подавляющему большинству не пришлось ничего учить.

Answer (score 6):

Разметка Markdown — это надмножество HTML, возможно использовать произвольные теги. Правда, на этом сайте ради безопасности имеются ограничения, и набор разрешённых тегов ограничен. Полный список вы найдёте [тут на мете](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5777).

Существует множество диалектов Markdown; тот, что используется на нашем сайте, полностью описан на странице [справки по редактированию](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/editing-help). Ознакомьтесь с ней, она не большая. Краткие руководства по использованию каждого элемента форматирования можно увидеть после нажатия знака вопроса в правом верхнем углу редактора.

В конце концов, достаточно писать внятный обычный текст, разделяя его визуально, просто чтобы его можно было прочитать даже без форматирования, и скорее всего, он будет выглядеть прилично. Исключением будет разве что исходный код программ, но его можно обернуть тегами `<pre>`.

```
<pre>... тут код ...</pre>
```

Или таки после вставки в поле редактирования выделить его и нажать <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> на клавиатуре или `{}` среди кнопок редактора.

Итого: не нравится Markdown — так не используйте его! Это окошечко, в котором я сейчас пишу, прекрасно понимает и обычный HTML. Не нравится HTML — не используйте и его! Пишите просто обычный текст, как в блокноте (*единственное* исключение см. выше).

Comment: Таблицы — жутко опасная штука )