# Перенос на Мету вопроса от участника с недостаточной для Меты репутацией

Tags: обсуждение, дефект, мета, перенос-вопросов

Недавно на Мету был перенесен вопрос [Почему у вас такой неудобный редактор WYSIWYG?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5746) с основного сайта. Он задан участником, репутация которого [недостаточна для задания вопросов на Мете](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/participate-in-meta). Стоило ли вообще в таком случае переносить этот вопрос или он должен был быть просто-напросто закрыт? А может быть здесь вовсе имеется дефект в движке?

Comment: А почему на мете есть ограничение на репутацию?

Comment: @Visman чтобы хотя бы первый вопрос задавался на основном сайте.

Answer (score 1):

Да стоит переносить. И так всё время делается.

Comment: Зачем? Есть удачные примеры? Или это просто такая традиция?

Comment: Потому что это логично.

Comment: Если бы это было логично, у меня вопрос бы не возник. Да и без мало-мальских объяснений я могу только поставить минус такому ответу.

Comment: Понятия не имею, как объяснить абсолютно логичное действие. И вообще, я ж вопросу минус не ставил.

Comment: Так у нас и не круговая порука, чтоб плюс за плюс и минус за минус. Мне хотелось бы услышать какие-то разъяснения, а не просто "так всегда делалось, это логично". Обоснование где?

Comment: Просто я не вижу причин, по которым вопрос, тематически относящийся к мете, не надо на неё переносить. Ну нет у него достаточной репутации, чтобы задать тут, но ведь вопрос-то тематически сюда относится.

Comment: Вот. Это уже походит на какую-то попытку объяснения, но есть одно "но" - вопрос в глубоком минусе, в частности из-за того, что участник даже справку по редактору не почитал, которая прямо под рукой находится! Поэтому, хорошо бы понять, а были ли случаи, когда подобные перенесенные вопросы были действительно полезны для Меты.

Comment: Зато ответы большие и в плюсе :)

Comment: В частности потому, что для голосования в "минус" тоже нужно иметь некоторую репу!

Comment: @alexolut дело не в том, что он не читал справку. Он там принципиально не хочет изучать технологию, которая нужна на одном захолустном сайте, в то время как весь просвещённый мир пишет на форумах в BBCode с богоугодными эмодзи.