# Какие теги HTML можно использовать на сайтах Stack Exchange?

Tags: поддержка, faq, редактор

Как известно, на сайтах сети Stack Exchange для оформления вопросов и ответов используется разметка [Markdown](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown). В соответствии со спецификацией Markdown, теги **HTML** и разметку **Markdown** можно беспрепятственно смешивать. При этом можно использовать лишь *часть* тегов HTML — иначе это был бы просто рай для [XSS](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B5%D0%B6%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3).

Какие теги HTML внесены в «белый список» и разрешены на Stack Exchange?

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса «http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1777/».</sub>

Answer (score 21):

### Разрешённые теги HTML

На Stack Exchange можно использовать только следующий **безопасный набор тегов HTML**:

```
<a>             — гипертекстовая ссылка.
<b>             — полужирное начертание; используйте только в крайнем случае, мы рекомендуем <h1> - <h3>, <em> и <strong>.
<blockquote>    — выделяет часть текста, представляющую собой цитату из другого источника.
<code>          — выделяет фрагмент компьютерного кода.
<del>           — удаление; используется для выделения изменений в тексте.
<dd>            — описание определённого элемента из списка описаний <dl>.
<dl>            — список описаний.
<dt>            — название элемента из списка описаний <dl>.
<em>            — выделение важного текста.
<h1>, <h2>, <h3> — заголовки.
<i>             — курсивное начертание.
<img>           — тег для изображений.
<kbd>           — обозначает ввод данных пользователем (как правило, ввод с клавиатуры).
<li>            — элемент в нумерованном <ol> или маркированном <ul> списке.
<ol>            — нумерованный список.
<p>             — абзац текста.
<pre>           — предварительное форматирование текста моноширинным шрифтом с сохранением всех переносов строк.
<s>             — перечёркнутый текст.
<sup>           — надстрочное написание, при котором текст расположен выше базовой линии на 1/2 высоты знака; используется для сносок и другого форматирования.
<sub>           — подстрочное написание, при котором текст расположен ниже базовой линии на 1/2 высоты знака.
<strong>        — выделяет важный текст.
<strike>        — устаревший тег для перечёркнутого текста; используйте вместо него тег <del>.
<ul>            — маркированный список.
<br>            — перенос текста на новую строку.
<hr>            — обозначает смену темы, обычно с помощью горизонтальной линии.
```

Поскольку вышеуказанные теги HTML разрешены, **для их отображения в тексте нужно экранировать символ `<`**. Для экранирования символа '<' его можно добавить в виде кода (используя отступ или обратные кавычки, как показано ниже) или как HTML-сущность `&lt;`.

### Разрешённые атрибуты

#### Атрибуты тега `img`

Атрибуты, которые можно использовать с тегом `<img>`, перечислены ниже. При этом учитывайте, что мобильный вид отображения принудительно устанавливает для атрибута `width` максимальное значение `90%`. Соответственно, при указании атрибута `height` изображение, возможно, не будет пропорционально масштабироваться на мобильных устройствах.

**Важен порядок указания атрибутов.** Некорректный порядок атрибутов (например, атрибут `height` предшествует атрибуту `width`) приведёт к удалению тега.

```
src=""
width="" (до 999; не добавляйте расширение 'px')
height="" (до 999; не добавляйте расширение 'px; см. примечание выше)
alt=""
title=""
```

#### Атрибуты тега `a`

Для тега `<a>` можно использовать следующие атрибуты:

```
href=""
title=""
```

### Важные примечания

- При генерировании страницы теги HTML, не указанные в списке выше, будут удалены. Возможно, они будут отображаться при предварительном просмотре страницы на стороне клиента, но затем на стороне сервера такие теги в любом случае будут удалены.
- **Следует указывать теги *в точности так, как показано выше*. Любое отклонение/добавление лишних пробелов, использование одинарной кавычки или пропуск кавычек и т. д. приведёт к тому, что тег будет удалён.**
- Использование тега `<table>` не допускается (и не будет добавлено в будущем). Сожалеем, но это решение было принято сознательно. Если вам нужно на скорую руку сделать таблицу, используйте тег `<pre>` и кодировку ASCII.

Comment: TL;DR: таблицы нельзя, остальное неважно. :)

Comment: Очень странно, что del в списке есть, а его компаньон [ins](http://htmlbook.ru/html/ins) - нет.

Comment: @Ainar-G `ins` выполняет подчеркивание, а [подчеркивание запрещено](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/117016/339911).

Comment: и почему тогда не поменять стили для `<ins>`, если уж так борятся с подчёркиванием..